# Saving and loading a Background object state using NSCoding

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nscoding

In my code I create an instance of the `ScrollingBackground` in the `BackgroundLayer` and the `BackgroundLayer` also creates an instance in the `GameScene`. I want to save the `ScrollingBackground` state so when a player dies I can return to it unchanged. Here is the relevant code:

ScrollingBackground.m:

```
-(id)initWithBackgroundLayer: (BackgroundLayer *)layer{
if (self = [super init]) {
    backgroundRepeatCount =0;
    scrollSpeed = 0.0; 
    backgroundCount = 0;
    backgroundArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]


bg = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bg1.png"];
bg.position = ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2);
[currentBatchNode addChild:bg];

bgSwap = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bg2.png"];
bgSwap.position = ccp(s.width/2, 3*s.height/2 -1.0);
[currentBatchNode addChild: bgSwap];

                .
                . 
                .
   }
}

-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {

[aCoder encodeObject:self.bg forKey:@"bg"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.bgSwap forKey:@"bgSwap"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.displayedBg forKey:@"displayedBg"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.backgroundArray forKey:@"backgroundArray"];
[aCoder encodeObject:self.currentBatchNode forKey:@"currentBatchNode"];    
        .
        .
        .
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *) aDecoder {

 self = [super init];
 if(self != nil) {

    self.bg = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bg"];
    self.bgSwap = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"bgSwap"];
    self.displayedBg = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"displayedBg"];
    self.backgroundArray = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"backgroundArray"];
    self.currentBatchNode = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"currentBatchNode"];
              .
              . 
              .
   }
}
```

EDITED:

1. How can I save the above state?
2. How can I load it again?
3. Is this the right way to save CCSprites and CCSpriteBatchNodes?

Comment: you are basically asking for design advice here. Give it a shake and come back with specific issues you are encountering in the persist/restore cycle, not a broad question like this.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: I edited the question. I hope it's more specific.

Comment: well, again asking for opinion. My opinion with respect to 3 is no, and 1&2 is : some other method. But then again, it is just me. Others will think otherwise.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg:more specifically, how can I solve the above issues?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: I wouldn't mind if you have another approach to solving this same issue. I am really out of options now.